# Select an element who's ancestor has child with a button

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find an element based on whether or not it's ancestor has child with a button.
The page has a list of containers. These containers will have one of two button options and sometimes no button at all. ('Join', 'Unjoin' and no button)
I only want the link from containers that have a specific button.
The problem is the link only shares a common ancestor in the container and isn't a parent or sibling.

The following XPath returns the desired button.

```
//*[@class='Class2']//*[Class4']//button[text()='Join']
```

The following XPath returns the all the links regardless of the button.

```
//*[@class='Class1']//*[@class='Class3']/a
```

I think I need something like this. But it's not returning any results. Class2 being the common ancestor. And I still need to filter on the button.

```
//*[@class='Class1']//*/ancestor::div[@class='Class2']/*[@class='Class3']/a
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly what you asked for?

Comment: Example HTML demonstrating the structure would be helpful in understanding what you are looking to achieve, and to be able to test a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to get all elements with `@class='Class2'` including inside them elements with `@class='Class4'` and button with text `Join` inside them the XPath locator can be

```
//*[@class='Class2' and (.//*[@class='Class4']//button[text()='Join'])]
```

Comment: No. This syntax means that the element itself has class name `Class2` and inside it there are elements matching `//*[@class='Class4']//button[text()='Join']` locator

Comment: Maybe I did not clearly understand what are you trying to achieve?